# How to startapp from inside docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, tdd, testdriven.io

I have a problem in the steps of testdriven.io The definitive guide to Django Celery, when i want to start a new tdd app if i execute these commands
`

```
$ docker-compose exec web bash

(container)$ ./manage.py startapp tdd
```

`
it creates an app that is read only and pycharm cant change read only status. Some solutions say that it is because i created the app from root user but i cannot understand how to solve it. Here are the Dockerfile and the Docker-compose.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: testdriven_web
    # '/start' is the shell script used to run the service
    command: /start
    # this volume is used to map the files and folders on the host to the container
    # so if we change code on the host, code in the docker container will also be changed
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8010:8000
    # env_file is used to manage the env variables of our project
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django

  redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: testdriven_celery_worker
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  celery_beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: testdriven_celery_beat
    command: /start-celerybeat
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  flower:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: testdriven_celery_flower
    command: /start-flower
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    ports:
      - 5557:5555
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

And the Dockerfile
`

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apt-get install -y gettext \
  # Additional dependencies
  && apt-get install -y procps \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY ./compose/local/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

`

I tried creating a user in the dockerfile using this as a base but i was unsuccessful [https://github.com/testdrivenio/django-on-docker/issues/10](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)